# What is a good way of showing files for downloads in PHP

Tags: php, download

I have the downloads section on my website. But i have folder structure where files reside inside folders.

I want that when someone click on downloads then i have the category list appears which are directories an then the files appears in nice format.

Any ideas

Comment: please add the piece of your code in which you made an attempt to reach your goal. This way it is easier for us to spot the problems and give you constructive answers. Without your code the best we can do is give educated guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
function printDir($d="") {
    $c = glob($d."*",GLOB_MARK);
    echo "<li>".($d == "" ? "ROOT" : array_pop(explode("/",substr($d,0,-1))))."<ul>";
    foreach($c as $x) {
        if( substr($x,-1) == "/") printDir($x);
        else echo "<li><a href=\"".$x."\">".array_pop(explode("/",$x))."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></li>";
}
echo "<ul>";
printDir();
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

This will print the contents of the current folder, with links to each file found, and also searches subfolders recursively.

Comment: Thanks Kolink. the problem is the directory is not publicly accessible. So how can i make user download from that location. Do i need to make temp copy.

Comment: Prepend "download.php" at the beginning of the urls: `<a href=\"download.php?file=".urlencode($x)."\">` Then that download.php file can simply call `readfile($_GET['file'])` (after setting appropriate headers)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache, you can do it by allowing index generation. Add the line

```
Options +Indexes
```

to the `.htaccess` file in your download directory (you can also set this option in the apache config file).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php) free downloader script. You will get something like a "Save to" window , so you can save your file anywhere on your hard disk.